# Is there an easy way to work with values of type Map k1 (Map k2 v)

Tags: haskell

I've run into this problem a few times and haven't found any standard solution, so I'm asking here.

For a specific example, imagine I have a list of pairs of words and their part of speech (I'm doing a natural language processing homework assignment), and I'd like to be able to, given a part of speech, look up the counts of the words I've encountered.

Is there an accepted solution? Any advice? A template haskell library that solves this for arbitrary depth maps (Hey, I can dream, can't I)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `Map (k1, k2) v` is unsuitable (perhaps if you need to extract and manipulate `Map k2 v`s), then it's not too hard to define composite Map manipulation functions. e.g.

```
lookup2 :: (Ord k1, Ord k2) => k1 -> k2 -> Map k1 (Map k2 v) -> Maybe v
lookup2 k1 k2 = lookup k2 <=< lookup k1
```

But I don't know of any template haskell library to generate these functions for you, sorry.

**EDIT** Here's my analogue of `insertWith`:

```
insertWith2 :: (Ord k1, Ord k2) => (v -> v -> v) -> k1 -> k2 -> v -> Map k1 (Map k2 v) -> Map k1 (Map k2 v)
insertWith2 f k1 k2 m = insert k1 (insertWith f k2 v $ fromMaybe empty $ lookup k1 m) m
```

Comment: My difficulty is in insertWith (I don't actually need insertWithKey, but it would be nice if I could figure it out).

Comment: Yeah, `lookup2` was probably the easiest one to write. See edit for my `insertWith2`.

Comment: Maybe later I'll write a TH library as an exercise in TH :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you should be able to use a map where the keys are pairs, e.g. `Map (k1, k2) v`, or in the general case maps where the keys are arbitrarily long lists of words, i.e. `Map [k] v`. Both tuples and lists implement `Ord` if their contents do, so this works straight out of the box.

That should be much more convenient to work with than nested maps.

Comment: I need to be able to get information on all k2s for a given k1. I'm aware that I can just filter, but that seems like not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can stand some indirection:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Monad

data Ord k => Nestedmap k v = Val v | Nest (M.Map k (Nestedmap k v))

-- return Nothing is the list of keys is either too long or too short.
-- might be better to signal this kind of error some other way,
-- to distinguish between this and a key not being present.
look :: Ord k => [k] -> Nestedmap k v -> Maybe v
look [] (Val v) = Just v
look _ (Val _) = Nothing
look [] _  = Nothing
look (k:ks) (Nest m) = M.lookup k m >>= look ks
```

So:

```
*Main Data.Map> let m = Nest $ fromList [("foo", Val 3), ("bar", Nest $ fromList  [("foo", Val 4), ("baz", Nest $ fromList [("quux", Val 5), ("foo", Val 9)])])]
*Main Data.Map> look ["bar","baz","quux"] m
Just 5
```

It would be trivial, though boring, to write functions to insert, update, etc., after a particular sequence of keys.

Comment: It's not particularly interesting if I need to supply all the keys at once (I can just use a tuple for that). It's more useful if, when given fewer than necessary keys, I get a new nested map (or nothing, if the key sequence failed).

Comment: Well, you can certainly do that with this approach, just define a function look :: Ord k => [k] -> Nestedmap k v -> Maybe (Nestedmap k v), which would return a value constructed either with Val or Nest. And it would more easily accept arbitrary levels of nesting than using lookup2, lookup3, etc.

Comment: e.g.:
look [] n = Just n
look (k:_) (Val _) = Nothing
look (k:ks) (Nest m) = M.lookup k m >>= look ks